# Separate multiple arrays in one string - Javascript - JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I have a string with multiple arrays in it seperated by comma. What I want to do is to parse each json-object (not array!) into one array in javascript. What's the best way to do it?

```
[  
   {  
      "type":"radio-group",
      "label":"Radio-Button-Gruppe",
      "name":"radio-group-1556028993486",
      "className":"iCheck",
      "values":[  
         {  
            "label":"aaaaaaa",
            "value":"aaaaaaa"
         },
         {  
            "label":"bbbbbbbbb",
            "value":"bbbbbbbbb"
         },
         {  
            "label":"cccccccccccc",
            "value":"cccccccccccc"
         }
      ]
   }
],
[  
   ...
],
[  
   {  
      "type":"header",
      "label":"Überschrift"
   }
]
```

Want to have this:

```
array[0] = {  
      "type":"radio-group",
      "label":"Radio-Button-Gruppe",
      "name":"radio-group-1556028993486",
      ...
   }

array[n] = {  
      "type":"header",
      "label":"Überschrift"
   }
```

**Solution**

```
JSON.parse(`[${formData}]`).flat();
```

With the `flat()`-Function I could remove the outer array brackets and parse my json-objects into my array.

Comment: [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it is missing only the wrapping square brackets. Have you tried:

```
let str = '...', // your string
    arr = JSON.parse(`[${str}]`).flat();
```